# Undefined Reference to Function in Library

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I'm working on my own math library, and I have a couple of non-member functions in the namespace I'm using for the library ("cml", like it matters much). Anyway, the library (which I'm building statically as a .a/.lib file) compiles just fine, but when I go to use the library in a test program, I get an error that the functions are undefined references.

This is header (func.h) file:

```
namespace cml
{

template <typename T>
T toRadians(T val);
template <typename T>
T toDegrees(T val);

template <typename T>
T fastSqrt(T val);
template <typename T>
T fastInverseSqrt(T val);

}
```

And this is the func.cpp file:

```
#include <CML/func.h>

#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits>
#include <cassert>

namespace cml
{

template <typename T>
T toRadians(T val)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559, "toRadians() requires the template parameters to be floating points.");

    return val * MATH_PI / 180;
}

template <typename T>
T toDegrees(T val)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559, "toDegrees() requires the template parameters to be floating points.");

    return val * 180 / MATH_PI;
}

template <typename T>
T fastSqrt(T val)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559, "fastSqrt() requires the template parameters to be floating points.");

    return T(1) / fastInverseSqrt(val);
}

template <typename T>
T fastInverseSqrt(T val)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559, "fastInverseSqrt() requires the template parameters to be floating points.");

    T tmp = val;
    T half = val * T(0.5);
    uint32* p = reinterpret_cast<uint32*>(const_cast<T*>(&val));
    uint32 i = 0x5f3759df - (*p >> 1);
    T* ptmp = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&i);
    tmp = *ptmp;
    tmp = tmp * (T(1.5) - half * tmp * tmp);
#if defined(CML_ACCURATE_FUNC) // If more accuracy is requested, run Newton's Method one more time
    tmp = tmp * (T(1.5) - half * tmp * tmp);
#endif // defined
    return tmp;
}

}
```

I am getting the error for all four of the functions. I am using the latest version of Code::Blocks, with GCC on Windows8. I am compiling for Win32. I've tried different suggestions I've found like marking the functions `extern`, but it doesn't seem to fix it. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, and if that is the case a second pair of eyes might help.

The error exactly: `undefined reference to`float cml::toRadians(float)'`

Comment: What **exactly** does the error message say?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I forgot that, the most important part. I'll add it now.

Comment: The template functions have to be in the header file -- otherwise they don't expand correctly at compilation time -- just like what @SleuthEye duplicate link says....

Answer (score 2):

You need to define template functions inside the header file. What I would do is

1. Rename func.cpp to func.inl, and make sure it is not being compiled with a C++ compiler.
2. Add the line `#include "func.inl"` to the bottom of func.h.

Template functions are not compiled like regular functions, but are handled by a later compilation stage (like inline functions).

Comment: @SleuthEye's link is worth reading as well. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: @SleuthEye's link is working for me as well. However this also helped with another error I was having. Thanks.